# Which chart library is used in the kickstarter dashboard?

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to find the chart library used in the kickstarter dashboard:

[image]
<sub>(source: [alexgpr.com](http://www.alexgpr.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Screen-Shot-2012-08-10-at-11.04.52-AM.png))</sub>

Why?
Because I need some functionality not available in many of the libraries I have found.

- Money in one side, percentage in the opossite side.
- An horizontal line parallel to the axis (like the green one in the image)
- Look nice and professional

Comment: It could be a custom solution. View the source of the webpage and look for any JS libraries.

Comment: Only users with an active Kickstarter project can view the chart so I can't look into the source...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say which library they use but it looks like it could be raphael.js or similar.
You can also do some great animations with http://raphaeljs.com/ It creates SVG graphics and is great on all browsers including IE6

Also for graphs specifically check out http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

the library that it is used looks like http://www.chartjs.org/